# Code to find double time of an exponential in R

Tags: r, date, graph, double, exp

I have a set of data, containing values which lie on an exponential curve with a high Pearson co-efficient. I need a way to find the average double time. The code would have to find how long it takes a value x to reach 2x, then average all of those times. Any other methods that would also give the double-time of an exponential would be fine. The two columns are Date (dttm) and value (dbl).

Comment: Can't you just do a linear regression of the log of the y value?

Comment: That's probably a good idea, I didn't think of that